# How to change the appearance of a SINGLE UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm brand new to iOS programming so I'm pretty sure that the answer is very simple however I can't seem to find it anywhere. I've seen other questions asking how to change the font size for all the UIAlertActions within an UIAlertController using UILabel.appearance(). I need to be able to do this for only one specific UIAlertAction.